Attempting to Authorize for Admin API
Unable to get an AccessToken using the client credential flow.
https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/admin-api/overview/authentication/clientcredentialsflow/
I ran this command and got the below response when I was expecting an accessToken.
Client_id
npx @jack-henry/banno-client-creds-helper client-assertion --client-id=65abc16c-2025-4828-9d0b-a7dc0de84070 --private-key=./private_key.pem
Client JWT payload: {
  "jti": "4540027b-7dcb-4510-aa64-f3bdcde2c68f",
  "aud": "https://banno.com/a/oidc-provider/api/v0/token",
  "sub": "65abc16c-2025-4828-9d0b-a7dc0de84070",
  "iss": "65abc16c-2025-4828-9d0b-a7dc0de84070",
  "exp": 1732227576098
}
Signed client JWT: eyJhbGciOiJQUzI1NiJ9.eyJqdGkiOiI0NTQwMDI3Yi03ZGNiLTQ1MTAtYWE2NC1mM2JkY2RlMmM2OGYiLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2Jhbm5vLmNvbS9hL29pZGMtcHJvdmlkZXIvYXBpL3YwL3Rva2VuIiwic3ViIjoiNjVhYmMxNmMtMjAyNS00ODI4LTlkMGItYTdkYzBkZTg0MDcwIiwiaXNzIjoiNjVhYmMxNmMtMjAyNS00ODI4LTlkMGItYTdkYzBkZTg0MDcwIiwiZXhwIjoxNzMyMjI3NTc2MDk4fQ.a1jgZUYv6RaMHgIYB1FVUX7Suia13vcT0CIlCTphxkWIwqvHABLRsfoU4P9n2ZB5FXvg4hE1rJP0tXROVWyHpTDSLcw8vKtwAnLWr46vYwsvvevWt0lB05INaYbeIewT_PRn4SF_Eax7ZJMBS1ti5Y5O2k7JpXTGVlf-jBOYgXgdoyIfonaeZbS0PntSUC4lv93CqwJ6gQh0A4SvknZGJGI0g-gYNzi_FznUDCShnVkukLJagwKKlbBoUwewagCZqkZfvyFSs6Uejz28oap_GXdZVLzpfxmJ2r4_e_fO76HPT-sUiZ04a2PC4jxJOK9m01Ak_9ODH78HucNfS40rew

You can inspect the JWT at https://jwt.io/

To obtain an access token, make a POST to the https://banno.com/a/oidc-provider/api/v0/token endpoint.
Include a content-type header of application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
Request body:
client_assertion=eyJhbGciOiJQUzI1NiJ9.eyJqdGkiOiI0NTQwMDI3Yi03ZGNiLTQ1MTAtYWE2NC1mM2JkY2RlMmM2OGYiLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2Jhbm5vLmNvbS9hL29pZGMtcHJvdmlkZXIvYXBpL3YwL3Rva2VuIiwic3ViIjoiNjVhYmMxNmMtMjAyNS00ODI4LTlkMGItYTdkYzBkZTg0MDcwIiwiaXNzIjoiNjVhYmMxNmMtMjAyNS00ODI4LTlkMGItYTdkYzBkZTg0MDcwIiwiZXhwIjoxNzMyMjI3NTc2MDk4fQ.a1jgZUYv6RaMHgIYB1FVUX7Suia13vcT0CIlCTphxkWIwqvHABLRsfoU4P9n2ZB5FXvg4hE1rJP0tXROVWyHpTDSLcw8vKtwAnLWr46vYwsvvevWt0lB05INaYbeIewT_PRn4SF_Eax7ZJMBS1ti5Y5O2k7JpXTGVlf-jBOYgXgdoyIfonaeZbS0PntSUC4lv93CqwJ6gQh0A4SvknZGJGI0g-gYNzi_FznUDCShnVkukLJagwKKlbBoUwewagCZqkZfvyFSs6Uejz28oap_GXdZVLzpfxmJ2r4_e_fO76HPT-sUiZ04a2PC4jxJOK9m01Ak_9ODH78HucNfS40rew&client_assertion_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Aclient-assertion-type%3Ajwt-bearer&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=openid%20full
Token POST error: 401 undefined
Headers {
  [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] {
    date: [ 'Thu, 21 Nov 2024 22:18:36 GMT' ],
    'content-type': [ 'application/json; charset=utf-8' ],
    'content-length': [ '77' ],
    connection: [ 'close' ],
    'x-request-id': [ 'becf8f6938c7c9fafe03566a3a489a27' ],
    'x-b3-traceid': [ '93b24d2c2dfee060eb1c4caa45d94706' ],
    'x-b3-spanid': [ 'b1f6cd49e1886530' ],
    'x-b3-sampled': [ '1' ],
    traceparent: [ '00-93b24d2c2dfee060eb1c4caa45d94706-b1f6cd49e1886530-01' ],
    'access-control-allow-origin': [ '*' ],
    'cache-control': [ 'no-store' ],
    'strict-transport-security': [ 'max-age=31536000' ]
  }
}

Token POST response: {
  "error": "invalid_client",
  "error_description": "client authentication failed"
}


Thanks for sharing the x-request-id - looking into it!

Hey @Sam were you able to take a look at this?

Hey @Sam I hope you had a good thanksgiving. Has there been any progress on this?

Hi Jakob! Have not forgotten about this - I passed along the x-request-id to the engineering team - since I couldn't find anything immediately wrong with the request, I'll be sure to follow up with the team if they can uncover anything.

So sorry for this - would it be possible to test again - if it's still unsuccessful share the new  x-request-id?

Here's an updated one @Sam
'a22d2cfac88c2bc52d144eb69c20dc5d'

To be clear! It is still not working.

Figured out the issue! It seems like the client ID you are using is for a Consumer external application and not an external application for the Admin API -  details on how to setup an external application for the Admin API is here: https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/admin-api/overview/configuration/
